# jq streaming eats first element, why?

Tags: json, jq

When using jq in streaming mode (because 100 GB file) it eats the first element. How can I avoid that?

```
echo [{"id":482,"a":"2","b":1},{"id":483,"a":"3","b":2}] | jq  -c --stream "fromstream(1|truncate_stream(inputs))"
```

Output is

```
{"a":"2","b":1}
{"id":483,"a":"3","b":2}
```

The first element (id) is missing from the first array element.

This is jq version 1.6. It is on Windows 2010, but the same behaviour is also on jq 1.6 on Ubuntu 22.04.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `--null-input` (or `-n`) flag. That way the standard input is set to `null`, and `inputs` can fetch all actual inputs.

```bash
jq -cn --stream "fromstream(1|truncate_stream(inputs))"
```

```json
{"id":482,"a":"2","b":1}
{"id":483,"a":"3","b":2}
```

Comment: That did the trick. Huge thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that's because you're using `inputs` with `--stream`.

```bash
$ echo '[{"id":482,"a":"2","b":1},{"id":483,"a":"3","b":2}]' \
| jq  -c --stream 'inputs'
[[0,"a"],"2"]
[[0,"b"],1]
[[0,"b"]]
[[1,"id"],483]
[[1,"a"],"3"]
[[1,"b"],2]
[[1,"b"]]
[[1]]
```

Using `.` seems better, but I'm not sure what you're after:

```bash
$ echo '[{"id":482,"a":"2","b":1},{"id":483,"a":"3","b":2}]' \
| jq  -c --stream '. as $i | (1 | truncate_stream($i))'
[["id"],482]
[["a"],"2"]
[["b"],1]
[["b"]]
[["id"],483]
[["a"],"3"]
[["b"],2]
[["b"]]
```

Comment: I can see this fixes my problem. But I want output to be json-formatted and I'm not sure how to modify your solution to this. I must admit I find jq syntax quite challenging.